# Como transformar uma sequência escrita em uma sequência numérica? (R)

Tags: r

Estou com problemas para manipular um banco do TSE. A parte abaixo do código o importa:

```
library(tidyverse)
locais_vot_SP <- read_delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/camilagonc/votacao_secao/master/locais_vot_SP.csv",
                        locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
                        delim = ",",
                        col_names = F) %>% 
              filter(X4 == "VINHEDO")

names(locais_vot_SP) <- c("num_zona", 
                      "nome_local",
                      "endereco",
                      "nome_municipio",
                      "secoes",
                      "secoes_esp")
```

Como pode ser notado, os dados da variável `secoes` não estão devidamente organizados, já que informações diferentes estão agregadas na mesma célula.

```
secoes
196ª; 207ª; 221ª; 231ª;
197ª; 211ª; 230ª; 249ª;
```

Com o código a seguir, comecei a consertar o problema:

```
locais_vot_SP <- locais_vot_SP %>% mutate(secoes = gsub("ª", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   mutate(secoes_esp = gsub("ª", "", secoes_esp)) %>%
                                   mutate(secoes_esp = gsub(";", "", secoes_esp)) %>%
                                   mutate(secoes = gsub("Da ", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   separate_rows(secoes, sep = ";") %>%  
                                   mutate(secoes = unlist(strsplit(locais_vot_SP$secoes, ";")))
```

Assim obtive o seguinte:

```
secoes
32 à 38
100
121
```

O que resta para ser solucionado são as células em que há `x à y`. Como chegar ao seguinte resultado?

```
secoes
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Para transformar qualquer cadeia alfanumérica do tipo `x não_número y`, com `x` e `y` dois números inteiros na sequência `x:y`, pode-se fazer do seguinte modo.

```
x <- "32 à 38"
y <- unlist(strsplit(x, "[^[:digit:]]+"))
y <- as.integer(y)
Reduce(`:`, y)
#[1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
```

Isto pode ser facilmente posto numa função.

```
camila <- function(x){
    y <- unlist(strsplit(x, "[^[:digit:]]+"))
    y <- as.integer(y)
    Reduce(`:`, y)
}

camila("32 à 38")
#[1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
```

(É claro que deverá escolher outro nome para a função.)